# 2-D array of zeroes and ones

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I want to generate a  2-D array of zeroes and ones so that it is 25% zeroes and 75% ones.

I know that I will be using the rand()%2 function but how do i limit the zeroes to be only 25 percent of the array?

Comment: You could create a non-random array of 25% zeroes and 75% ones and shuffle it.

Comment: What you can do is set everything to 1 and then randomly pick 25% of the available indexes and make them 0.

Comment: @Amgad, can you clear it up if you want a **perfect** 25%/75% distribution or only a expected distribution of 25%/75%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize every element of the array with the following:

```
int zeroOr1() { // Generates 
    static std::default_random_engine gen;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,3);
    return (dist(gen) % 4) >= 1;
}
```

Because `dist(gen) % 4` produces one of `[0, 1, 2, 3]` about equally likely, `(dist(gen) % 4) >= 1` will evaluate to `true` about 75% of the time and `false` about 25% of the time.

Note: this doesn't guarantee a perfect 25/75 distribution like the other answers, but it works for all array sizes. I'd need more information about the application to decide if this is good enough or not suitable.

Comment: [rand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) does not make any guarantees as to the quality of the pseudo-random numbers generated. In particular, there is no guarantee about equal distribution.

Comment: @IInspectable, fixed, uses `std::uniform_int_distribution` now

Comment: @WorldSEnder how does this guarantee an equal distribution?

Comment: @m.s., It's as good as it gets, using the standard. If you need a better distribution, you can change the `gen` to a better distribution. But I think the default distribution will perform okay in this case.

Comment: but your solution does NOT guarantee a 25 / 75 distribution, it could be e.g. 24/76

Comment: But this way, there is no guaranty that there is exactly 75%/25%. Shuffle is the right way to guaranty that.

Comment: @m.s., I see what you mean. But it can't be done for a 2D array of size [3, 3], anyway. OP underspecified his question I think.

Comment: Just because you cannot guarantee a 1/4 : 3/4 distribution for all dimensions doesn't mean, you shouldn't try. [m.s.' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31346345/1889329) is better in this respect (and it should be the accepted answer).

Comment: I added a note so that everybody can see

Answer (score 2):

Create vector of size `N` with zeroes.
Set the first `N*0.75` elements to one.
Randomize the vector.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>

int main ()
{
  std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );

  const int N = 100;
  const int zero_percent = 25;
  const int one_percent = 100-zero_percent;

  const int one_count = (N * one_percent)/100;


  std::vector<int> v(N);
  std::fill(v.begin(), v.begin()+one_count, 1);

  std::random_shuffle (v.begin(), v.end());


  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

live example: http://ideone.com/CdlaMy

Comment: For `N` < 100, you're generating 100% zeros. You probably meant to write `const int one_count = N * one_percent / 100.0 + 0.5;`.

Comment: @IInspectable you are right, I changed to division by `100.0`

Comment: `N * one_percent / 100` is enough. Floating point not required.

Comment: @Jarod42 right, I was not considering left to right execution order

Comment: @Jarod42: Floating point math produces more accurate results, if [done right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346161/2-d-array-of-zeroes-and-ones#comment50676465_31346345).

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't see why (with float)`2*25%==1` and `2*75%==2` is more correct than (with int) `2*25%==0` and `2*75%==1`. and even your solution may be written as `(N * percent + 50) / 100`

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 0s and 1s, one possible solution would be keeping all the coordinates in some kind of a "set" and randomly taking out then ( N/M /4 (n and m are the sizes of the array ) times ( to get 25% random coordinates) ) and mark as 1, then mark the rest as 0.